# propagating errors through an ANOVA?

Tags: anova, error-propagation

I'm sorry if this question has been answered before. I have a dataset:

```
  -1.5   -1.8    -1.625
  -1.25  -1.525  -1.675
  -1.15  -1.35   -1.65
```

etc

Each column is a treatment, each number is a sample. I want to divide each treatment by another number of similar magnitude and units, but this number has a standard deviation that was calculated (from confidence intervals). There's no variation in that dataset because of the nature of the measurement. I'd like to run an ANOVA and maybe some pairwise comparisons on the resulting data (after subtraction), but I'm not sure what to do with the error term in the calculation parameter.

Thanks!

To be more specific:

```
   tmt 1    tmt 2   tmt 3
   -1.5     -1.8    -1.625
   -1.25    -1.525  -1.675
   -1.15    -1.35   -1.65
   -1.1     -1.45   -0.65
   -0.9     -0.9    -0.9
   -0.9     -1.15   -0.85
   -1.35    -1.6    -1.6
   -0.9     -1.8    -1.8
   -1.35    -1.4    -1.5
```

This is the original dataset. Each column is a treatment, and each row within a column is an individual sample. I have an additional parameter for teach treatment (tmt). This additional parameter has a standard deviation associated with each treatment:

```
   tmt 1    tmt 2   tmt 3
   -1.1     -1.5    -2.5

   stdv 1   stdv 2  stdv 3
   0.051    0.153   0.087
```

This is in the same units as the above dataset. I subtract the additional parameter from the original dataset to get a second dataset. The parameter (small table above) that was associated with each treatment (column) was subtracted from every sample in the original treatment:

```
   tmt 1   tmt 2   tmt 3
   -0.4     -0.3    0.875
   -0.15    -0.025  0.825
   -0.05    0.15    0.85
   0        0.05    1.85
   0.2      0.6     1.6
   0.2      0.35    1.65
   -0.25    -0.1    0.9
   0.2      -0.3    0.7
   -0.25     0.1    1
```

This second dataset is what I want to run an ANOVA on, to look at differences in this calculated parameter between species. I'm not sure how (or if its even required) to take the error term from the additional parameter into account.

Sorry about the nebulous question - I'm pretty new to all this

Comment: Please clarify the question. What you show as ":data" are just numbers, without an indication of which ones come from different samples -- or, for that matter, whether some of them are the "another numbers" you refer to. It'd also help if you showed more concretely what those other measurements are. It's all pretty nebulous as stated.

Comment: To what does "that dataset" refer?  What connection does it have to the standard deviation referred to in the preceding sentence?  What kind of "subtraction" is going on?  To what does the "error term in the calculation parameter" refer--the "number [with] a standard deviation"?

Comment: I added an edit that hopefully explains the question more concretely

Comment: Thanks! That's clear enough to give it a go.  You might get more comments asking for additional clarification, but please bear with us: they aim at producing focused, accurate, objective answers.